# Derivative of a trace w.r.t matrix within log of matrix sums

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus, trace

I'm trying to solve an optimization (sub)problem and am running into trouble with a tricky derivative. I'd like to find the matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}_+$ which minimizes the following function, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}_+$, $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

$f= \mathrm{tr}(W\log(X+C)L\log(X+C)^T)$

Here, $\log$ and the addition are element-wise. It would be convenient if a closed form solution exists for
$\min\limits_{C > \mathbf{0}} f(C)$,
where the other variables are fixed.

My attempt:

$f = \sum\limits_{i}[W\log(X+C)L\log(X+C)^T]_{ii}$

$=\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j}\sum\limits_{k}\sum\limits_{l}W_{ij}\log(X_{jk}+C_{jk})L_{kl}\log(X_{il}+C_{il})$

$\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta B}=\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta C_{jk}} + \dfrac{\delta f}{\delta C_{il}}$

$=\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j}\sum\limits_{k}\sum\limits_{l}\dfrac{
W_{ij}L_{kl}\log(X_{il}+C_{il})}{X_{jk} + C_{jk}} + \dfrac{
W_{ij}\log(X_{jk}+C_{jk})L_{kl}}{X_{il} + C_{il}}$

Which, in matrix notation, I take to be:

$=\dfrac{WL\log(X+C)^T}{X+C} + \dfrac{W\log(X+C) L}{(X+C)^T}$

Setting this equal to zero, I see no obvious solution except except for $C=-X$ which violates my assumption.

I'm hoping someone would be able to check that I've differentiated correctly, at least, and perhaps suggest an alternative minimization scheme (perhaps some subgradient method) in this event.

Comment: Well, in the scalar case, depending on the sign of $WL$, the optimal solution is either $0_+$ or $\inf$, i.e, the problem is unbounded or solution (in limit) on the border of feasible set. Hence, stationary point not interesting

Comment: Elements in $W$, $L$, can be positive or negative (or zero, in theory).

Comment: Sure. What I am saying is that you cannot simply look for stationary points. Optimal points are either at stationary points, at the border or at infinity

Comment: Ok, thanks for that clarification. If I have some reasonable prior on bounds for values of elements of B, is there some other way of finding stationary points? Either due to a local minimum or at a saddle point?

Comment: $B$?. Not that it makes it any easier than what you have now (you already described bounds, $C>0$). A stationary point can not be made any easier to find, it is what it is (a point where derivative is zero). It has nothing to do with the constraints.

Comment: Oops, I meant '$C$', thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ lynn , you divide by $X+C$ !!! Yet, your final equation is correct.

$f$ is a function of $C$. If $H\in M_{n,d}$, then let $K=[k_{i,j}]=[\dfrac{h_{i,j}}{x_{i,j}+c_{i,j}}]$. If $C$ is a stationnary point, then, for every $H$, $Df_C:H\rightarrow tr(WKLlog(X+C)^T+Wlog(X+C)LK^T)=tr(Llog(X+C)^TWK+L^Tlog(X+C)^TW^TK)=0.$

It is also true for every $K$ ; then $Llog(X+C)^TW+L^Tlog(X+C)^TW^T=0$, that is equivalent to the lynn's condition.

Thus $log(X+C)\in\ker Z$ where $Z=W^T\otimes L + W\otimes L^T$ (stacking row by row) is a symmetric matrix. Let $(\lambda_i)_i=spectrum(W),(\mu_i)_i=spectrum(L)$. If $W,L$ are normal matrices, then the spectrum of $Z\in M_{nd,nd}$ is $(2Re(\lambda_i\mu_j))_{i,j}$ and $Z$ is not a bijection iff there is $(i,j)$ s.t. $Re(\lambda_i\mu_j)=0$. Otherwise we cannot conclude.

EDIT: As Johan wrote, your problem is not clear. Assume for instance that $w_{r,r}l_{s,s}<0$. We choose $C=[c_{i,j}]$ s.t. the $(c_{i,j})_{i,j}$ are small positive numbers except $c_{r,s}$ which is a great positive number. Then $f(C)\sim w_{r,r}l_{s,s}(log(c_{r,s}))^2$ when $c_{r,s}$ tends to $+\infty$. Thus the inferior bound of $f$ is $-\infty$.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Its going to take a little mental processing for me to grok, but I will accept as correct asap.

Comment: Two questions: 1) this notation: $log(X+C)\in\ker Z$ means 'in the kernel matrix Z'? That's equivalent to its nullspace? 2)  I'm not sure the expression, $Z=W^T\otimes L + W\otimes L^T$, works out since $W$ and $L$ are of different (symmetric) dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: @ zzk, 1. yes.  2. $Y=W^T\otimes L$ and  $Y^T=W\otimes L^T$ are in $M_{nd,nd}$ ; thus $Z=Y+Y^T$ is defined and symmetric. cf.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Ok, thanks... I was mistakenly reading that as the Schur product (I've been reading some papers with some non-standard notation lately)!

Answer (score 1):

First, solve the problem for $G = \rm{log}(X+C)$.

In terms of $G$, the derivative is
$$
  \frac {\partial f} {\partial C} = \frac {W^TGL^T + W G L} {X+C} 
$$
Setting it to zero and taking the $\rm{vec}$ of both sides
$$ \eqalign {
  (L\otimes W^T + L^T\otimes W)\,\, \rm{vec}(G) &= 0 \cr
  K\,g &= 0 \cr
  (I+K)\,g &= g \cr
}$$
So $g$ is an eigenvector of $(I+K)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, if it exists.  After finding $g$, it is easy to recover $G$, and finally $C = (\rm{exp}(G)-X)$.